# Prevent APK to compile again after decompilation

Tags: android

I decompiled my apk, did some changes and compiled again to make APK.
Is there any way to prevent it from compile again after decompilation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protect android application from piracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711247/protect-android-application-from-piracy)